# Nodos se sobrescriben, listas enlazadas en C

Tags: c++, c, nodos

tengo un problema con este ejercicio de listas enlazadas, la consigna es hacer un registro de pacientes en un hospital donde se puedan agregar y dar de alta pacientes y ver el registro de pacientes entre otras cosas. El problema es que al ingresar pacientes al registro y luego ver la lista de pacientes resulta que se sobrescriben todos los datos, y por lo tanto imprime en pantalla los datos del ultimo paciente ingresado de manera repetida. Ya revise bastante el codigo y no se he podido identificar el problema.
Se que el código es una mezcla de C y C++, pero asi lo usan en mi universidad.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

typedef struct nodo{
    char *nombre, *enfermedad, *edad, *peso, *altura;
    struct nodo *next;
}NODO;



NODO* nodoalfinal(NODO* inicio, char *nombre, char *enfermedad, char *edad, char *peso, char *altura);

NODO* borrarnodo(NODO* inicio, char *nombre);

void imprimirlista(NODO* inicio);

int main() {
    NODO *inicio=NULL;
    int res, menu;
    char enfermedadaux[20], nombreaux[20], paciente[20], pesoaux[10], alturaaux[10], edadaux[10];
    marca:
    //MENU
    printf("\nIngrese 1 para dar de alta un paciente\nIngrese 2 para agregar un paciente al registro\nIngrese 3 para obtener los datos de un paciente\nIngrese 4 para mostrar los registros de todos los pacientes\nIngrese 5 para salir\n");
    scanf("%d",&res);
    switch(res){
        case(1):{
            printf("Ingrese el nombre del paciente:");
            fflush(stdin);
            gets(paciente);
            fflush(stdin);
            inicio=borrarnodo(inicio,paciente);
            printf("\n------PACIENTE DADO DE ALTA------");
        }break;
        case(2):{
            printf("Ingrese el nombre del paciente:");
            fflush(stdin);
            gets(nombreaux);
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("\nIngrese la condicion que padece el paciente:");
            fflush(stdin);
            gets(enfermedadaux);
            printf("\nIngrese la edad del paciente:");
            fflush(stdin);
            gets(edadaux);
            printf("\nIngrese el peso del paciente:");
            fflush(stdin);
            gets(pesoaux);
            printf("\nIngrese la estatura del paciente ej(1.8m) :");
            fflush(stdin);
            gets(alturaaux);
            inicio=nodoalfinal(inicio, nombreaux, enfermedadaux, edadaux, pesoaux, alturaaux);
            printf("\n------PACIENTE INGRESADO------");
        }break;
        case(3):{
            printf("Ingrese el nombre del paciente:");
            fflush(stdin);
            gets(paciente);
            fflush(stdin);
            while((inicio!=NULL)and(strcmp(inicio->nombre,paciente)!=0)){
                inicio=inicio->next;
            }
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("Nombre:%s Diagnostico:%s Edad:%s Peso:%s Altura:%s\t",inicio->nombre, inicio->enfermedad, inicio->edad, inicio->peso, inicio->altura);
        }break;
        case(4):{
            imprimirlista(inicio);
        }break;
        case(5):{
        }break;
    }
    printf ("\nDesea volver al menu principal?\n\n1- Si\n2- No\n\n");
    scanf ("%d", &menu);
    
    switch (menu){
        
    case 1: {system("cls");goto marca;}
    case 2: return 0;
    
    }
    return 0;
}

NODO* nodoalfinal(NODO* inicio, char *nombre, char *enfermedad, char *edad, char *peso, char *altura){
    NODO *nuevo = new NODO;
    nuevo->nombre=nombre;
    nuevo->enfermedad=enfermedad;
    nuevo->edad=edad;
    nuevo->altura=altura;
    nuevo->peso=peso;
    nuevo->next=NULL;
    
    if (inicio == NULL){
        inicio = nuevo;
    }
    else{
        NODO *aux = inicio;
        while (aux->next != NULL)
            aux = aux->next;
        aux->next=nuevo;
    }
    return inicio;
}
    
    NODO* borrarnodo(NODO* inicio, char *nombre){
        NODO *aux, *anterior;
        aux=inicio;
        if((inicio!=NULL)and(strcmp(inicio->nombre,nombre)!=0)){
            aux=inicio;
            inicio=inicio->next;
            free(aux);
        }
        else{
            while((aux!=NULL)and(strcmp(aux->nombre,nombre)!=0)){
                anterior=aux;
                aux=aux->next;
            }
            if(aux!=NULL){
                anterior->next=aux->next;
                free(aux);
            }
        }
        return inicio;
    }
        
        void imprimirlista(NODO* inicio){
            NODO *actual= new NODO;
            actual=inicio;
            while(actual!=NULL){
                printf("%s %s %s %s %s\n", actual->nombre, actual->enfermedad, actual->edad, actual->peso, actual->altura);
                actual=actual->next;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Si dices que es en C, ¿Por qué pones como etiqueta C++? ¿Por qué usas  `<iostream>`? No me queda claro si la respuesta la esperas en C o en C++ (y no, "Cualquiera de los dos me vale" no es una respuesta aceptable)

Comment: @eferion Buenas, como aclare mas arriba, en  mi universidad nos dan lenguaje c asi como lo he escrito, yo soy consiente de que uso algunas librerías o funciones de c++, pero asi nos hacen programar. Si me pudieras dar una respuesta en C me vendria de diez, gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Se que el código es una mezcla de C y C++, pero asi lo usan en mi universidad.

Si en tu universidad quieren sacar catetos allá ellos. De ti depende sacar algo positivo de tu paso por la universidad o no.

Por poner un ejemplo, la documentación es muy explícita respecto al uso de [`fflush`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fflush/):

> In all other cases, the behavior depends on the specific library implementation. In some implementations, flushing a stream open for reading causes its input buffer to be cleared (but this is not portable expected behavior).

Básicamente viene a decir que, en el resto de situaciones (cuando un stream no es de escritura, el comportamiento depende en exclusiva de la versión de la librería que estés usando. Te pone como ejemplo que usar `fflush` sobre un stream de lectura (`stdio`), podría provocar la limpieza del buffer, pero que este comportamiento no es portable (ni está garantizado).

Resumiendo, ese uso es peligroso porque bajo otro compilador u otra versión de tu compilador podría comportarse de forma indefinida (su comportamiento no está definido en ningún sitio). Podría funcionarte, el programa podría morir, o podría quedarse bloqueado, o podría ... vete tu a saber.

Alguno se escudará en que claro, que C no tiene una forma estándar de limpiar el buffer de entrada. Bueno, es una verdad a medias, ya que perfectamente podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
while (getchar() != EOF);
```

Este sencillo bucle vaciará el buffer de entrada

O, si no te gusta, elimina `printf` y `scanf` y usa los objetos propios de C++ para entrada/salida:

```
// Leemos un dato
std::cin >> dato;

// Vaciamos el buffer de entrada
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max());
```

> Si me pudieras dar una respuesta en C me vendria de diez

Pues ya tenemos un problema, resulta que en C **no existe** la instrucción `new`. Tu código únicamente compila en C++. Si no eres capaz de distinguir entre C y C++ el problema al final lo vas a tener tu, no tu universidad.

> El problema es que al ingresar pacientes al registro y luego ver la lista de pacientes resulta que se sobrescriben todos los datos

Lógico y normal que pase eso, veamos:

Por un lado declaras un array de caracteres:

```
char enfermedadaux[20];
```

Después almacenas en este buffer con datos introducidos por el usuario

```
gets(enfermedadaux);
```

Y después creas un nodo para la lista. Al hacer esto inicializas el puntero para que apunte al buffer antes mencionado:

```
inicio=nodoalfinal(inicio, enfermedadaux);
//                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <-- referencia al buffer

NODO* nodoalfinal(NODO* inicio, char *enfermedad){
NODO *nuevo = new NODO;
nuevo->enfermedad=enfermedad;  // <<--- asignación de punteros
```

Con esto consigues que **todos** los nodos apunten a los mismos buffers y, en consecuencia, tendrás tantos elementso repetidos como nodos tengas en la lista.

Es lo que tiene programar *"como lo hacen en la universidad"*.

Tienes dos posibles soluciones:

1. Usas arrays en vez de punteros:

   ```
    struct nodo{ // En C++ no hay que usar typedef para los structs
        char *nombre[20];
        char* enfermedad[20];
        // ...

        nodo *next; // En C++ no hay que usar struct X para declarar variables
    };
   ```

   Ahora bien, como ahora son arrays y no punteros, el programa te obliga a copiar los datos de un array a otro:

   ```
    NODO* nodoalfinal(NODO* inicio, char *enfermedad){
    NODO *nuevo = new NODO;
    strcpy(nuevo->enfermedad, enfermedad);
    // ...
   ```
2. Te dejas de chorradas de usos heredados de C y explotas el potencial de C++. En este caso usas `std::string` para las cadenas de caracteres:

   ```
    struct nodo{ // En C++ no hay que usar typedef para los structs
        std::string nombre;
        std::string enfermedad;
        // ...

        nodo *next; // En C++ no hay que usar struct X para declarar variables
    }; 

    int main() {
        std::string enfermedadaux;

        std::cin >> enfermedadaux; // No hace falta limpiar el buffer!!!

        inicio=nodoalfinal(inicio, enfermedadaux);
    }

    NODO* nodoalfinal(NODO* inicio, std::string const& enfermedad)
    {
        NODO *nuevo = new NODO;
        nuevo->enfermedad=enfermedad;  // si, ahora la asignacion funcionaria como esperas
     }
   ```

Comment: muchas gracias!